# Spring cloud client with remote logging config problems

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

My infraestructure is simple, I have a git server, a spring cloud config server and a microservice that takes the configuration from the config server and git.
I get this config file from app-name:

```
server:
  port: 8893
logging:
  config: http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:3000/admin123/config-repository/raw/master/log4j2.xml
```

And my log4j2 config xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="all" name="MyApp" packages="">
    <Appenders>
        <Syslog name="RFC5424" format="RFC5424" host="xxx.xx.xx.75" port="514"
            protocol="TCP" appName="MyApp" mdcId="mdc" includeMDC="true"
            facility="SYSLOG" enterpriseNumber="18060" newLine="true" messageId="Audit" id="App" 
            reconnectionDelayMillis="100000">
        </Syslog>
        <Async name="Async">
            <AppenderRef ref="RFC5424" />
        </Async>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.mycorp" level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="Async" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="Async" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The problem is that the application starts logging on the syslog and then starts logging to the console, but stoping writing on the syslog.
So, the log4j config is readed together with the application config but something happend in the middle.
Is like the log config applies just for the bootstrap of the application.
I made some local tests and I know that the looging.config must be plased on the application.yml, not in the bootstrap.yml, if I do that, I get the same result.
Maybe I disclaim some concept.

Here is the last part of the syslog:

> > hod.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor@3cfdd348] supports [class org.springframework.cloud.config.environment.Environment]
> >     2015-10-07T20:16:05+00:00 ip 1 2015-10-07T17:17:20.465-03:00 rMyName MyApp - Audit - Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor@449591d4] supports [class org.springframework.cloud.config.environment.Environment]
> >     2015-10-07T20:16:05+00:00 ip 1 2015-10-07T17:17:20.469-03:00 rMyName MyApp - Audit - Written [Environment [name=micro-central-get-ticket, profiles=[default], label=master, propertySources=[PropertySource [name=classpath:/config/micro-central-get-ticket.yml]]]] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@4e3a58ee]
> >     2015-10-07T20:18:40+00:00 ip 1 2015-10-07T17:19:55.118-03:00 rMyName MyApp - Audit - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
> >     2015-10-07T20:18:40+00:00 ip 1 2015-10-07T17:19:55.118-03:00 rMyName MyApp - Audit - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@5469414b
> >     2015-10-07T20:18:40+00:00 ip 1 2015-10-07T17:19:55.118-03:00 rMyName MyApp - Audit - Successfully completed request
> >     2015-10-07T20:18:40+00:00 ip 1 2015-10-07T17:19:55.118-03:00 rMyName MyApp - Audit - Publishing event in org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4d0b0fd4: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/micro-central-get-ticket/default]; client=[127.0.0.1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[dispatcherServlet]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[618967ms]; status=[OK]
> >     2015-10-07T20:18:40+00:00 ip 1 2015-10-07T17:19:55.118-03:00 rMyName MyApp - Audit - Publishing event in org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@34f7234e: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/micro-central-get-ticket/default]; client=[127.0.0.1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[dispatcherServlet]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[618967ms]; status=[OK]

And there the log writen on the console:

> ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
>   [2015-10-08 11:01:43.803] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- CentralGetTicketApplication: Starting CentralGetTicketApplication on rMyName with PID 6488 (C:\workspaces\microservicios-quini6-v3\micro-central-get-ticket-test\target\classes started by rMyName in C:\workspaces\microservicios-quini6-v3\micro-central-get-ticket-test)
>   [2015-10-08 11:01:43.847] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- AnnotationConfigApplicationContext: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@710b18a6: startup date [Thu Oct 08 11:01:43 GMT-03:00 2015]; root of context hierarchy
>   [2015-10-08 11:01:43.980] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
>   [2015-10-08 11:01:44.192] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- CentralGetTicketApplication: Started CentralGetTicketApplication in 3.049 seconds (JVM running for 3.869)
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:07.221] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration: Located property source: CompositePropertySource [name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource [name='classpath:/config/micro-central-get-ticket.yml']]]
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:07.244] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext: Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@64f555e7: startup date [Thu Oct 08 11:03:07 GMT-03:00 2015]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@710b18a6
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:07.983] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:08.103] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean 'infoEndpoint': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=infoEndpoint; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointAutoConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$InfoEndpointRebinderConfiguration; factoryMethodName=infoEndpoint; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/RefreshAutoConfiguration$InfoEndpointRebinderConfiguration.class]]
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:08.125] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- DefaultListableBeanFactory: Overriding bean definition for bean 'default.null.RibbonClientSpecification': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClientSpecification]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClientSpecification]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:08.263] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- GenericScope: BeanFactory id=2ee54948-4ea0-303c-9a4e-7ecb6a22bf0b
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:08.269] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:08.288] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker: Bean 'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7b077a16] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:08.410] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker: Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ab1f6fb] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:08.426] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker: Bean 'transactionAttributeSource' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:08.435] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker: Bean 'transactionInterceptor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:08.442] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker: Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:08.472] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker: Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fbb4e411] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:08.725] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer: Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8893 (http)
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:08.839] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- StandardService: Starting service Tomcat
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:08.840] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- StandardEngine: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:08.962] boot - 6488  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- [/]: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:08.963] boot - 6488  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- ContextLoader: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1719 ms
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:09.528] boot - 6488  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- ServletRegistrationBean: Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:09.534] boot - 6488  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- FilterRegistrationBean: Mapping filter: 'metricFilter' to: [/*]
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:09.534] boot - 6488  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- FilterRegistrationBean: Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:09.534] boot - 6488  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- FilterRegistrationBean: Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:09.534] boot - 6488  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- FilterRegistrationBean: Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:09.534] boot - 6488  INFO [localhost-startStop-1] --- FilterRegistrationBean: Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:09.957] boot - 6488  WARN [main] --- URLConfigurationSource: No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:09.957] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- URLConfigurationSource: To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:09.965] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- DynamicPropertyFactory: DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@734ce281
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:10.269] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- RequestMappingHandlerAdapter: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@64f555e7: startup date [Thu Oct 08 11:03:07 GMT-03:00 2015]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@710b18a6
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:10.328] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- RequestMappingHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public ar.com.boldt.common.business.model.response.central.TicketInfoResponse ar.com.boldt.getticket.controller.GetTicketController.obtenerTicket(ar.com.boldt.common.business.model.request.central.TicketInfoRequest)
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:10.330] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- RequestMappingHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:10.330] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- RequestMappingHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:10.365] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- SimpleUrlHandlerMapping: Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:10.365] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- SimpleUrlHandlerMapping: Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:10.421] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- SimpleUrlHandlerMapping: Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.014] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/shutdown],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.ShutdownMvcEndpoint.invoke()
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.015] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/restart],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.context.restart.RestartMvcEndpoint.invoke()
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.015] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/env],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.value(java.util.Map)
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.016] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/env/reset],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.Map org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManagerMvcEndpoint.reset()
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.016] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/info],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.016] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.016] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/env],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.017] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/health],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(java.security.Principal)
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.017] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/mappings],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.017] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/pause],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.018] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.018] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/metrics],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.018] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/refresh],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.018] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/resume],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.GenericPostableMvcEndpoint.invoke()
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.018] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/configprops],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.018] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/archaius],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.019] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/autoconfig],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.019] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/beans],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.019] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/dump],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.019] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/trace],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.157] boot - 6488  WARN [main] --- URLConfigurationSource: No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.157] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- URLConfigurationSource: To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.174] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- AnnotationMBeanExporter: Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.206] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- AnnotationMBeanExporter: Bean with name 'refreshEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.206] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- AnnotationMBeanExporter: Bean with name 'restartEndpoint' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.207] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- AnnotationMBeanExporter: Bean with name 'configurationPropertiesRebinder' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.207] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- AnnotationMBeanExporter: Bean with name 'refreshScope' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.207] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- AnnotationMBeanExporter: Bean with name 'environmentManager' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.210] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- AnnotationMBeanExporter: Located managed bean 'environmentManager': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager]
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.224] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- AnnotationMBeanExporter: Located managed bean 'restartEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.restart:name=restartEndpoint,type=RestartEndpoint]
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.236] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- AnnotationMBeanExporter: Located managed bean 'refreshScope': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh:name=refreshScope,type=RefreshScope]
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.244] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- AnnotationMBeanExporter: Located managed bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinder': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.properties:name=configurationPropertiesRebinder,type=ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder]
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.252] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- AnnotationMBeanExporter: Located managed bean 'refreshEndpoint': registering with JMX server as MBean [org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config:name=refreshEndpoint,type=RefreshEndpoint]
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.255] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- DefaultLifecycleProcessor: Starting beans in phase 0
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.258] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- EurekaConfigBasedInstanceInfoProvider: Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.657] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- DiscoveryClient: Disable delta property : false
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.657] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- DiscoveryClient: Single vip registry refresh property : null
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.657] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- DiscoveryClient: Force full registry fetch : false
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.657] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- DiscoveryClient: Application is null : false
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.657] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- DiscoveryClient: Registered Applications size is zero : true
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:11.657] boot - 6488  INFO [main] --- DiscoveryClient: Application version is -1: true
>   [2015-10-08 11:03:12.721] boot - 6488 ERROR [main] --- DiscoveryClient: Can't get a response from http://xxx.xx.xxx.57:8761/eureka/apps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will never work, spring boot documentation allow you to use logging.config only to pass the config file as a parameter to the jar for example, if you can use it writing the url into your config, spring boot with override the value and will use the console logging way.